# Unable to open chromium based browsers: libc++abi: __cxa_guard_acquire detected recursive initialization

Tags: 22.04, browser

I am unable to open any chromium based browsers on my PC having ubuntu 22.04. I am able to open firefox though. I tried to open google chrome from my terminal, but I get the following error.

```
prasanna@PrasLaptop:~$ google-chrome
libc++abi: __cxa_guard_acquire detected recursive initialization: do you have a function-local static variable whose initialization depends on that function?
```

As requested by [popey](https://askubuntu.com/users/612/popey), I have added the output of the following commands:

```
(base) prasanna@PrasLaptop:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
(base) prasanna@PrasLaptop:~$ ldd /opt/google/chrome/chrome
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd78def000)
    /usr/local/lib/AppProtection/libAppProtection.so (0x00007f5cfa600000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5d080c7000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5d080c2000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f5d08062000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f5cfa8c6000)
    libnss3.so => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss3.so (0x00007f5d07f33000)
    libnssutil3.so => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnssutil3.so (0x00007f5cfa894000)
    libsmime3.so => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmime3.so (0x00007f5cfa86a000)
    libnspr4.so => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnspr4.so (0x00007f5cfa82a000)
    libatk-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f5cfa5d6000)
    libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f5cfa59e000)
    libcups.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcups.so.2 (0x00007f5cfa500000)
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f5cfa327000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f5cfa311000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f5cfa2c3000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f5cfa292000)
    libatspi.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0 (0x00007f5cfa258000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f5cfa171000)
    libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f5cfa031000)
    libXcomposite.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007f5cfa02c000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f5cfa027000)
    libXext.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f5cfa012000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f5cfa00a000)
    libXrandr.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007f5cf9ffb000)
    libgbm.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgbm.so.1 (0x00007f5cf9fea000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f5cf9fc0000)
    libxkbcommon.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007f5cf9f79000)
    libpango-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f5cf9f12000)
    libcairo.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007f5cf9dea000)
    libasound.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2 (0x00007f5cf9ce5000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f5cf9cc5000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5cf9a00000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5d080f0000)
    libXi.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f5cf9cb1000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f5cf9600000)
    libffi.so.8 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8 (0x00007f5cf9ca4000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f5cf9c2c000)
    libplc4.so => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplc4.so (0x00007f5cf99f9000)
    libplds4.so => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplds4.so (0x00007f5cf99f4000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f5cf99a0000)
    libavahi-common.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavahi-common.so.3 (0x00007f5cf9992000)
    libavahi-client.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavahi-client.so.3 (0x00007f5cf997e000)
    libgnutls.so.30 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007f5cf9415000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f5cf9962000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f5cf995b000)
    libmount.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1 (0x00007f5cf9917000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f5cf98eb000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f5cf934e000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f5cf98de000)
    libwayland-server.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-server.so.0 (0x00007f5cf98c8000)
    libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f5cf98c2000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f5cf98ba000)
    libfribidi.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfribidi.so.0 (0x00007f5cf989c000)
    libthai.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0x00007f5cf9891000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f5cf927f000)
    libpixman-1.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007f5cf91d4000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f5cf9847000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f5cf910c000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f5cf90d1000)
    libxcb-shm.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f5cf9840000)
    libxcb-render.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f5cf9831000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f5cf9006000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f5cf8fd7000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f5cf8fd1000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f5cf8fc3000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f5cf8e88000)
    libidn2.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007f5cf8e67000)
    libunistring.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007f5cf8cbd000)
    libtasn1.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007f5cf8ca5000)
    libnettle.so.8 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.8 (0x00007f5cf8c5f000)
    libhogweed.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.6 (0x00007f5cf8c17000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f5cf8b95000)
    libblkid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007f5cf8b5e000)
    libpcre2-8.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007f5cf8ac7000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f5cf8a9c000)
    libzstd.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 (0x00007f5cf89cd000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f5cf89ad000)
    libcap.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2 (0x00007f5cf89a2000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f5cf8864000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f5cf884c000)
    libdatrie.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0x00007f5cf8841000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f5cf881a000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f5cf8811000)
    libbrotlidec.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlidec.so.1 (0x00007f5cf8803000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f5cf87fc000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f5cf87e6000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f5cf87c0000)
    libmd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmd.so.0 (0x00007f5cf87b3000)
    libbrotlicommon.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlicommon.so.1 (0x00007f5cf8790000)
(base) prasanna@PrasLaptop:~$
```

The laptop model is HP Elitebook 840 g6, core i7 8th gen.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of the following commands: `lsb_release -a` and `ldd /opt/google/chrome/chrome`. Also, what exact model of laptop is this?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I encountered a similar error, although it may not be the exact same issue you are facing. However, if anyone comes across a similar problem in the future, my experience might be helpful. In my case, I installed the Citrix Workspace App using the .deb package. During the installation, there was a prompt asking whether to enable app protection.

The error was occurring because I had enabled this option. The solution that worked for me was to reinstall Citrix Workspace App, but this time with the app protection option disabled, it's not the best solution tho.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it worked!

Answer (score 3):

App protection* in Citrix Workspace app is there for a reason: security.
At work they won't want me to switch it off (by reinstalling).

I'll be using Citrix Workspace app on my work laptop. As soon as that's working properly I'll remove Citrix Workspace app from my private pc.
But I can imagine that that's no option for everyone.

It would be nice if other apps (for me it's primarily Signal) could be whitelisted in Citrix Workspace app, somehow.

*) https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/tech-zone/design/reference-architectures/access-control.html#citrix-secure-private-access-app-protection-policies